# Position vector of a particle moving with constant speed on a straight line

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

Suppose we have a particle which starts from a point $A$ and moves with constant speed $u$ along the line $AB$.

One wants to show that the position vector $\mathbf{x}$ of the particle at time $t$ is $$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{a}+ut\frac{\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}}{|\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}|},$$ where $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are the position vectors of $A$ and $B$ relative to an arbitrary origin.

So, first we write down the vector equation of the straight line passing through two points $A$ and $B$, that is $$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{a}+k(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}),$$ where $k$ is a parameter. From the position equation of the particle $$\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{v}_0t+\mathbf{x}_0,$$ at any time $t$, we have $\mathbf{x}_0=\mathbf{a}$ at $t=0$ .

But I am stuck on how to derive that $\mathbf{v_0}$ is equal to $u\frac{\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}}{|\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}|}$.

I would appreciate any help or suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{b-a}$ is a vector in the direction from $\mathbf{a}$ to $\mathbf{b}$. Dividing by its length produces a unit vector in that direction.

Then multiplying by the (presumably positive) scalar $u$ produces a vector of magnitude $u$ in the direction from $\mathbf{a}$ to $\mathbf{b}$, which is precisely what you want as the velocity vector.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So we have velocity $=$ speed $\times$ direction?

Comment: Yes, but your "$\times$" is just scalar multiplication of a vector. Speed is a scalar (no direction, just a magnitude), and here "direction" is a unit vector

Answer (score 1):

You need a unit vector for the direction of motion, otherwise the speed gets multiplied by the length of the vector, so the net speed is off. Dividing $\mathbf b-\mathbf a$ by its length takes care of that.